# ASAM ODS Database Access from Python

Tags: python, database, database-connection, measurement

Is there a way to access ASAM ODS* databases using python? 
ASAM ODS is a well-defined standard for measurement data, seems sensible that there is a python library for it, but I can't find anything.

*Association for Standardization of Automation and Measuring Systems Open Data Services

Nothing to do with .ods OpenDocument Spreadsheets!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access using python, you need ASAM ODS server and client, have you using any ODS server? Which version?
If already there is an ODS server then you have to compile the ods531.idl (depends on the server ods version) with omniORB and omniORBpy, which will give you the required python library, refer [this](http://www.bioinformatics.org/bradstuff/bc/IntroPythonClient.pdf) to know how to write python CORBA client

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [asammdf](https://pypi.org/project/asammdf/) library.